# why css break of arrow using jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

When I make a simple demo of pop up having 2 or 3 items my triangle arrow is visible on the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/TFX6p/8/

When I add more items and set `height` and `overflow:auto;` my triangle arrow does not display, why?

http://jsfiddle.net/TFX6p/12/

```
<div data-role="page" id="MainPage">
    <div data-role="popup" id="Mainnavpanel" data-theme="b" data-arrow="b">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li> <a href="#MainPageheader" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn">Close</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Page1.html" class="ui-btn" data-transition="none">Page1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Page2.html" class="ui-btn" data-transition="none">Page2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Page3.html" class="ui-btn" data-transition="none">Page3</a>

            </li>

               <li> <a href="#MainPageheader" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn">Close</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Page1.html" class="ui-btn" data-transition="none">Page1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Page2.html" class="ui-btn" data-transition="none">Page2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Page3.html" class="ui-btn" data-transition="none">Page3</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="header" id="MainPageheader" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-fullscreen="false">
         <h1>Header</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">content</div>
     <a href="#Mainnavpanel"  data-rel="popup" data-role="button" >openpopup</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scroll` on `ul element` will not work, try to apply `width-height` on outer `div#Mainnavpanel-popup` like,

```
#Mainnavpanel-popup{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/TFX6p/13/)

**Updated** if it should be visible then apply **css** on class `ui-listview` like,

```
.ui-listview{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/TFX6p/15/)

Comment: it should be visible every time .can ite is possible ? traingle one

Comment: is it possible it is vissible ata every time user not want to scroll

Comment: can you look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483103/can-we-go-one-level-up-node-using-jquery

Comment: @user3530755 I added an answer of your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23486718/1817690) try that.